# How to change the size of a struct using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am making a struct with undefined size.

```
#define namemax 128
struct Image{
  char name[namemax+1];
  int length;
  double *array;          //double array[256]
};
  struct Image* graph;

  graph=malloc(max*sizeof(struct Image));
```

If I define `array[256]`, everything work fine.
but if I use `double *array`, and then write

```
graph[check].array = malloc( 100 * sizeof(double *));
```

it creates a segment fault.
I was wondering how can I define the size using `malloc` and `realloc` for array.
If I add value in the array, it shows segment fault.

```html
struct Image* graph;//outside the while loop
while:  //it is inside the while loop  
        //basically it read different name each line, and put the x and y to the array
        graph[check].array = malloc( 100 * sizeof(double));
     check++;
     strcpy( graph[check].name,type);
     graph[check].array[count]=shiftX;
     graph[check].array[count+1]=shiftY;
```

Comment: Your code is legal, but no guarantee that the malloced array is "after" the object, so it doesn't actually increase the object size.

Comment: **How** are you getting SIGSEGV?  `graph[check].array = malloc( 100 * sizeof(double)); graph[check].array[55] = 2.5;` should work just fine - **assuming** the call to `malloc()` succeeds.  Post more code.

Comment: I just update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because `double * array` is declaring a pointer to an array, not storage. You want to declare storage here. The easiest way is to simply define the array as `double array[1]` and make sure it's the last element in the struct. You can then allocate space for the structure using malloc() and realloc() by passing them the size of the base struct plus the size of the array (sizeof double * the number of array elements).

Comment: Declaring a pointer field in a structure like `double *array` then using `malloc()` to allocate memory is perfectly legal and won't cause SIGSEGV by itself.  It won't be located in adjacent memory, but it won't fail on its own.  There's more going on here.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is using sizeof(double *) instead of sizeof(double) even if both are the same if you're using x86-64 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

i think it makes seg fault because in malloc you have said `sizeof(double *)` (Actually you declare an array of array).
Just try to say `sizeof(double)` it may work but I dont know that for sure because I haven't tested it.

And by the way when you declare array staticly you reserve space for it when you declare your struct variable but when you declare it as pointer ( dynamic array ) you should reserve space for it and you can change the array's size. You should use `realloc` google it.